# Selenium Python cycle n + 1

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
while int(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".quantity").text) < 2:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id='box-most-popular'] [class='image-wrapper']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".quantity [type='submit']").click()
    n = ???
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='cart']/a[2]/span[.= '%d']" % (n+1))))
    driver.back()
```

i wanna increase variable "n" each of interaction inside the locator

`(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='cart']/a[2]/span[.= '%d']" % (n+1))`

but I don't know what I should put in "n" for it works,
original selector looks like "`//div[@id='cart']/a[2]/span[.= '1']`"
and in this part I need him increase `.= '1'` like: `.= '2'` then `.= '3'` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your counter `n` outside of loop and then increase it `+1` on each iteration:

```
n = 1
while int(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".quantity").text) < 2:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id='box-most-popular'] [class='image-wrapper']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".quantity [type='submit']").click()
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='cart']/a[2]/span[.= '%d']" % n)))
    n += 1
    driver.back()
```